# roxygen2: S4 generic functions are not exported unless a method is also defined

Tags: r, generics, roxygen2

It seems that as of version `4.0.0` [roxygen2](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/index.html) (running on `R-3.1.0`) changed something with respect to the exporting mechanism for S4 generics:

When a package only contains the generic but **no actual method for it yet**, the generic will not be exported even though its roxygen code features the `@export` tag (only leads to an empty `export()` entry in the `NAMESPACE` file).

Is this a bug or am I overlooking some sort of a "paradigm shift" here?

The reason why I'd like to be able to build packages with nothing but generics in it is to follow interface paradigms in the style of the the [SOLID design principles](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/60845/The-S-O-L-I-D-Object-Oriented-Programming-OOP-Prin).

### UPDATE

I looked around the source code a bit and found this:

```
# Functions that take complete partitum and return NAMESPACE lines
ns_export <- function(tag, part) {
  if (!is.null.string(tag)) return(export(tag))
  # FIXME: check for empty exports (i.e. no name)

  default_export(part$object, part)
}
```

This gave me the idea to try and provide an explit `tag` along with the `@export` tag:

```
#' @export foo
```

I also tried `@exportPattern` the same way:

```
#' @exportPattern foo
```

While this still results in a `export()` line in the `NAMESPACE` file, it does seem to be a workaround as `export(foo)` and `exportPattern(foo)` are there now as well! Still not sure if this is really the desired way to do it.

I've updated the illustration accordingly.

### Illustration

For the sake of easy reproducability you'll find the complete R package illustrating this behavior on [github](https://github.com/Rappster/roxygen2.problem).

Or see below to see directly what's going on.

---

Sole generic, export "fails":

```
#' Foo 1
#'
#' @description 
#' I would like to export this as a mere interface for \emph{other} packages. 
#' There shall be no default method that will be provided by \emph{this} package.
#' 
#' @param x \strong{Signature argument}. Main input argument.
#' @export

setGeneric(name = "foo1", signature = "x", def = function(x) {
    standardGeneric("foo1")
})
```

Sole generics, export successful (two alternatives):

```
#' Foo 2
#' 
#' @param x \strong{Signature argument}. Main input argument.
#' @export foo2

setGeneric(name = "foo2", signature = "x", def = function(x) {
    standardGeneric("foo2")
})

#' Foo 3
#' 
#' @param x \strong{Signature argument}. Main input argument.
#' @exportPattern foo3

setGeneric(name = "foo3", signature = "x", def = function(x) {
    standardGeneric("foo3")
})
```

Generic plus one actual method:

```
#' Bar
#'
#' @description 
#' Just for illustration purposes, this is a generic for which \emph{this}
#' package also provides a method.
#' 
#' @param x \strong{Signature argument}.
#'      Main input argument.
#' @rdname bar-method
#' @export

setGeneric(name = "bar", signature = "x", def = function(x) {
    standardGeneric("bar")
})

#' @param x  \code{\link{ANY}}.   
#' @return \code{\link{character}}. \code{"Hello World!"}
#' @rdname bar-method
#' @aliases bar
#' @export

setMethod(f = "bar", signature = signature(x = "ANY"), 
    definition = function(x) {
        "Hello World!"
})
```

Standard function:

```
#' Foo Bar
#'
#' @param x \code{\link{character}}.
#' @return \code{\link{character}}. Prints \code{x} and returns it.
#' @export

fooBar <- function(x) {
    print(x)
    x
}
```

Assuming everything is in a proper R package structure, running these commands will roxygenize the code and build the package:

```
## Packages //
require("devtools")
require("roxygen2")

## Set working directory //
setwd("path/to/package/roxygen2.problem")

## Roxygenize //
roxygenize()

## Build //
build(binary=TRUE)

## Install //
install()
```

You'll then end up with the following `NAMESPACE` content:

```
# Generated by roxygen2 (4.0.0): do not edit by hand

export()
export(foo2)
export(fooBar)
exportMethods(bar)
exportPattern(foo3)
```

As you see, exports work for

1. combinations of generics plus at least one actual method
2. sole generics when tags/patterns are provided for `@export` or `@exportPattern`
3. standard R functions

but not for sole generics that just feature `@export` (without any tag).

Comment: BTW I'd think seriously before applying any design recommendations from message-passing OO systems to R.